# AFNetwork 2.0 dealing with 401

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking, http-status-code-401

Is there a way to deal with `401` and refresh token using `AFNetwork 2.0` in a centralized way?

I'm able to solve the problem with my on implementation of `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

I did overriding the `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` method to retry the same request after getting a new access token.

But if I do that I'm unable to cancel the original request 'cause we're creating new ones.

My question is, could we create a new request encapsulating the new one inside the original so I could cancel the request and also canceling all the retry logic?